# How to receive base64 conversion [audio file] through TCP/IP with less seconds?

Tags: java, base64

Case: Two Different Linux Machine. Client Machine running on 'C'programming and Sever receiving machine running on Java.

My code:

```
appendedLen  = "2687868";
int lengthToCheck= inFromClient.read(ch, 0, ch.length);  

while (appendedLen >= lengthToCheck) {
    request = request + String.valueOf(ch).trim();

    if ((appendedLen - lengthToCheck) != 0) {
        ch = new char[appendedLen - actualLen];
        actualLen = inFromClient.read(ch, 0, ch.length);

        lengthToCheck = lengthToCheck + actualLen;
    } else {
        (" Received Entire Response");
        break;
    }
}
```

For receiving, it will take 6-7 Mins.

Answer (score 0):

Get InputStream from the socket and then use [Apache Commons](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#toByteArray(java.io.InputStream)) to read as byte[] as follows

```
IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream)
```

Comment: This will work for sending files from Client to Server but again it fails in receiving end. After logs enhancement, I have noticed that, at the average of 1448 bytes files receiving in my end.                                                               **Jumbo frame** will work  in my case?

Comment: did you try any 3rdparty lib for transferring large data, i found some discussion here http://serverfault.com/questions/111813/what-is-the-best-way-to-transfer-a-single-large-file-over-a-high-speed-high-lat